# What does the group_ids parameter of the TimeSeriesDataSet class specifically do in PyTorch Forecasting?

Tags: python, pytorch, time-series, forecasting

I am currently working with PyTorch Forecasting and I want to create dataset with TimeSeriesDataSet. My original data lies in a pandas Dataframe and looks like this:

```
date         amount        location 
2014-01-01     5               A
2014-01-01     7               B
    ...       ...             ...
2017-12-30     4               H
2017-12-31     8               I
```

So in total I got nine different unique values in "location" and an amount for each location per date. Now I am wondering what the *group_ids* parameter for the TimeSeriesDataSet class does and what it exact behaviour is? I am not really getting the idea based on the [documentation](https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pytorch_forecasting.data.timeseries.TimeSeriesDataSet.html?highlight=target#pytorch_forecasting.data.timeseries.TimeSeriesDataSet.multi_target).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A time-series dataset usually contains multiple time-series for different entities/individuals.

[`group_ids`](https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pytorch_forecasting.data.timeseries.TimeSeriesDataSet.html?highlight=target#pytorch_forecasting.data.timeseries.TimeSeriesDataSet.multi_target) is a list of columns which uniquely determine entities with associated time series. In your example it would be `location`:

> **group_ids** (*List[str]*) – list of column names identifying a time series. This means that the group_ids identify a sample together with the `time_idx`. If you have only one timeseries, set this to the name of column that is constant.

Comment: Can you please explain what "uniquely determine entities with associated time series" mean? I don't understand

Comment: @lalaland the row's key, in database language. In inventory data, it might be product ID. In personal data it might be name, surname, and date of birth.

Comment: I see thanks. for the history of electricity consumption can it be the location? does that make sense?

Comment: @lalaland if there's only one row/time series per location, then yes.